# Getting text to line up in center of div squares

Tags: html, css

I'm working on adding text to a disappearing/appearing square system written with HTML and CSS. Would there be a simple way to go about adding a paragraph tag to the *center* of each square? Here's my code:
jsfiddle.net/busterroni/wBcWc/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off not using a `<p>` tag as they include default margins. You can use a plain `<span>` with a class easier. Use `line-height:100px` (same as `height`) and text-`align:center;` to center the text horizontally and vertically.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/FYPAt/)

**HTML**

```
<span class="wrapper">
    <div class="rowone" class="a"><span class="hoverable">test</span></div>
    ...
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
}
.hoverable{
   color:transparent;    
}
.hoverable:hover{
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
```